# BatchInserters.batchDatabase fails - sometimes - silently to persist node properties

Tags: neo4j

I use **BatchInserters.batchDatabase** to create an embedded **Neo4j 2.1.5** data base. When I only put a **small amount** of data in it, everything works **fine**.

But if I increase the size of data put in, **Neo4j fails to persist** the latest **properties** set with setProperty. I can read back those properties with getProperty before I call shutdown. When I load the data base again with new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase those properies **are lost**.

The strange thing about this is that **Neo4j doesn't report any error** or throw an exception. So I have no clue what's going wrong or where. Java should have enough memory to handle both the small data base (**Database 2.66 MiB**, 3,000 nodes, 3,000 relationships) and the big one (**Database 26.32 MiB**, 197,267 nodes, 390,659 relationships)

It's hard for me to extract a running example to show you the problem, but I can do if this helps. Here the **main steps** I do though:

```
def createDataBase(rules: AllRules) {
    // empty the data base folder
   deleteFileOrDirectory(new File(mainProjectPathNeo4j))

    // Create an index on some properties
   db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(mainProjectPathNeo4j)
   engine = new ExecutionEngine(db)
   createIndex()
   db.shutdown()

    // Fill the data base
   db = BatchInserters.batchDatabase(mainProjectPathNeo4j)  
   //createBatchIndex
   try {
   // Every function loads some data
   loadAllModulesBatch(rules)
   loadAllLinkModulesBatch(rules)
   loadFormalModulesBatch(rules)
   loadInLinksBatch()
   loadHILBatch()
   createStandardLinkModules(rules)
   createStandardLinkSets(rules)
   // validateModel shows the problem 
   validateModel(rules)
   } catch {
      // I want to see if my environment (BIRT) is catching any exceptions
    case _ => val a = 7
   } finally {
  db.shutdown()
   }
 }
```

validateModel is **updating some properties** of already created nodes

```
def validateModule(srcM: GenericModule) {
  srcM.node.setProperty("isValidated", true)
  assert(srcM.node == Neo4jScalaDataSource.testNode)
  assert(srcM.node eq Neo4jScalaDataSource.testNode)
  assert(srcM.node.getProperty("isValidated").asInstanceOf[Boolean])
```

When I finally use **Cypher** to get some data back
the properties set by validateModel are missing

```
class Neo4jScalaDataSet extends ScriptedDataSetEventAdapter {
  override def beforeOpen(...) {
    result = Neo4jScalaDataSource.engine.profile(
      """
      MATCH (fm:FormalModule {isValidated: true}) RETURN fm.fullName as fullName, fm.uid as uid
      """);    
    iter = result.iterator()
 }

 override def fetch(...) = {
   if (iter.hasNext()) {

    for (e <- iter.next().entrySet()) {
     row.setColumnValue(e.getKey(), e.getValue())
    }

    count += 1;
    row.setColumnValue("count", count)

    return true   
   } else {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, result.executionPlanDescription().toString())
    return super.fetch(dataSet, row)
   }
 }
```

Comment: Could you quickly try if that happens with 2.1.3 or 2.1.4 too? How many of the latest properties are lost?

Comment: Oh, could you please not use the batchDatabase ? please use `BatchInserters.inserter` the batch-database is a leaky abstraction that should have never been written :)

Comment: I have switchted from 2.1.4 to 2.1.5 just today since I have encountered the problem with 2.1.4. But both show the same effect.

Comment: I just switch my code to use BatchInserters.inserter - again. Again because I have initially started with BatchInserters.inserter, but it showed to be slower than batchDatabase. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

batchDatabase indeed causes this problem.
I have switched to BatchInserters.inserter and now everything works just fine.